# I need to create a finite automata

Tags: finite-automata, computation-theory, dfa, deterministic

Consider the language L of all strings made of the symbols 0, 1 and 2 (Σ = {0, 1, 2}) where the last symbol is not smaller than the first symbol. E.g., the strings 0, 2012, 01231 and 102 are in the language, but 10, 2021 and 201 are not in the language.

As 0 is in the language and I don't understand why, I can't figure out if strings 1 and 2 are in the language?

So could someone please tell me if 1 and 2 as a string themselves are in the language and why?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

'0' is in the language because the first symbol and last symbol in '0' are both '0'. This satisfies the requirements that the last is not smaller than the first.

This means that the same applies for '1', '2', *and for the empty string* ''.